# Minitest's equivalent to RSpec's receive

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest

In Rspec one can do

```
expect(foo).to receive(:bark)
```

What's the equivalent in MiniTest?

(`assert_send` seems to not have a different behavior)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question was already answered here: [How to assert certain method is called with Ruby minitest framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869417/how-to-assert-certain-method-is-called-with-ruby-minitest-framework)

In short - you should use mocks for checking is the method was called.